# BootStrap 3 - Fixed navbar doesn't seems to be working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just beginning with twitter bootstrap 3.
I just made this fixed navigation bar, but it doesn't seems to be working.
The navbar isn't fixed.

Here's the code.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
                <!--  ==========  -->
                <!--  = Logo =  -->
                <!--  ==========  -->
                <div class="span7">
                    <a class="brand" href="index.html">
                        <span class="pacifico">Webmarket</span> 
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============= -->
    <!-- NavBar -->
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find Your Mac</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Live Link :- http://robocorp.in/design/
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why are you using both the *container* and *container-fluid* classes? Also, can you please set up a fiddle on http://bootply.com/?

Comment: I tried your code, fixing the css and bootstrap js dependencies and seem to work. Are you sure that you are importing bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css correctly? I also commented out main.css, seemed to work.

Comment: @ederollora

Both the files are linked correctly.
I commented out the main.css file as well, still doesn't seems to be working.
Also, I tried <div class="row"></div> (to check if this class works), this class doesn't work as well.

Comment: @9997

I'm a newbie. I just thought that using container-fluid would make everything responsive.

Comment: Updated the code with a live link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-15 col-center">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find Your Mac</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this and let me know. You have way too many span icon bars for the support for other devices, so I removed a couple.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

These don't exist on your webserver. I suggest putting the CSS In a folder called "assets" and then refering to them like so:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the same with the JS

Comment: This is what I get :- http://robocorp.in/design/
Also, I required a fixed header.

Comment: Are you even including the CSS and JavaScript properly? It doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: view-source:http://robocorp.in/design/

If I check the source, I see all the links are correct mate.

Comment: You have "toggle navigation" written for sr-only devices. You can't do this, and as I said, you have too many spans. If you did as I said, your menu bar would work. Like so: [link](http://colonelfalcon.com/robo/)

Comment: Also, please don't just copy my code, my bootstrap is different to yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Find Your Mac</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```